# Trying to scrape information from an iterated list of links using Beautiful Soup or ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape an [xml database](http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml)  list of links for [these addresses](http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/milano). (The 2nd link is an example page that actually contains some addresses. Many of the links don't.)

I'm able to retrieve the list of initial links I'd like to crawl through, but I can't seem to go one step further and extract the final information I'm looking for (addresses).

I assume there's an error with my syntax, and I've tried scraping it using both beautiful soup and Python's included library, but it doesn't work.

BSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

resultsdict = {}
companyname = []
url1 = 'http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml'

html = requests.get(url1).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
# find the links to companies
company_menu = bs.find_all('loc')
for company in company_menu:
    data = bs.find("html",{"i"})
    print data
```

Non 3rd Party:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

req = requests.get('http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml')
root = et.fromstring(req.content)
for i in root:
    print i[0].text
```

Any input is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: So you need to follow those links and extract information available under those links? You simply need to issue a series of new get requests for this links, and then parse information there. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is ok. You need to simply follow those links in the first page, here's how it will look like for the Milano page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

resultsdict = {}
companyname = []
url1 = 'http://www.agenzia-interinale.it/sitemap-5.xml'

html = requests.get(url1).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
company_menu = bs.find_all('loc')
for item in company_menu:
    if 'milano' in item.text:
        subpage = requests.get(item.text)
        subsoup = BeautifulSoup(subpage.text)
        adresses = subsoup.find_all(class_='riquadro_agenzia_off')
        for adress in adresses:
            companyname.append(adress.text)
print companyname
```

To get all addresses you can simply remove if 'milano' block in the code. I don't know if they are all formatted according to coherent rules, for milano addresses are under div with class="riquandro_agenzia_off", if other subpages are also formatted in this way then it should work. Anyway this should get you started. Hope it helps.